# AttributeError: 'EditViewDevis' object has no attribute 'render'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Need help again.
My aim is to create a quote and allow the user to add items dynamically.
I'm having trouble validating the grouped form: 'EditViewDevis' object has no attribute 'render'.

My createView class and updateView class are not working.
I got always this error: AttributeError at /nrn/ebe907fe-9711-4657-9319-4b7cb7873ff6/editdevis/.
'EditViewDevis' object has no attribute 'render'

I thought the error was due to my form_valid function,
What did I do wrong?

Any ideas how to resolve this error?
Here's my code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Article, Customer, Devis

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'gerant', 'siret', 'email', 'phone', 'address']

class DevisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Devis
        fields = ['customer', 'paid', 'comments']
        labels = {
            "customer": "Nom Client",
            "paid": "Paid ? ",
            "comments": "Comments",
        }

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['designation', 'category', 'quantity', 'unit', 'prix_unit', 'devise', ]  

ArticleFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Devis, Article, form=ArticleForm, fields=['designation', 'quantity', 'prix_unit', ], extra=5, can_delete=True, can_delete_extra=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from nrn_app.forms import ClientForm, DevisForm, ArticleForm, ArticleFormSet
from nrn_app.models import Article, Customer, Devis

class DevisInline():
    form_class = DevisForm
    model = Devis
    template_name = "devis/devis.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        articles = self.get_articles_formsets()
        if not all((x.is_valid() for x in articles.values())):
            return self.render(self.get_context_data(form=form))

        self.object = form.save()
        for name, formset in articles.items():
            formset_save_func = getattr(self, 'formset_{0}_valid'.format(name), None)
            if formset_save_func is not None:
                formset_save_func(formset)
            else:
                formset.save()
        return redirect('nrn:home-devis')

    def formset_articles_valid(self, formset):
        articles = formset.save(commit=False)
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()
        for article in articles:
            article.product = self.object
            article.save()

class AddViewDevis(DevisInline, CreateView):
    """
    Créer un devis
    """
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddViewDevis, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = self.get_articles_formsets()
        context["title_devis"] = "Création devis"
        context["submit_text"] = "Créer"
        return context

    def get_articles_formsets(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            return {'articles': ArticleFormSet(prefix='articles'), }
        else:
            return {'articles': ArticleFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, prefix='articles'), }


class EditViewDevis(DevisInline, UpdateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditViewDevis, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = self.get_articles_formsets()
        context["title_devis"] = "Modification devis"
        context["submit_text"] = "Editer"
        return context

    def get_articles_formsets(self):
        return {
            'articles': ArticleFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, instance=self.object, prefix='articles'),
            }
```

devis/devis.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} 
    <div class="entete">
        <h2> {{ form.slug }} </h2> 
        <a href="{% url 'nrn:home-devis' %}"> Retour liste devis</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container mt-4">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="devis_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>{{title_devis}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ form.non_form_errors }}
                {{ form }}
                <hr>

                <h5 class="text-info">Add Articles</h5>
                {{ articles.non_form_errors }}
                {{ articles.management_form }}

                {% for article in articles.articles %}
                <div class="d-flex py-1 inline {{ articles_formsets.prefix }}">
                    <div>{{article.designation.label}}: {{ article.designation }}</div>
                    <div class="ml-4">{{article.quantity.label}}: {{ article.quantity }}</div>
                    <div class="ml-4">{{article.prix_unit.label}}: {{ article.prix_unit }}</div>
                    {% if articles.articles.can_delete %}
                        <div class="ml-4"> {{ article.DELETE }} {{ article.DELETE.label }} </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 mb-5">
            <button type="submit" class="px-5 btn btn-info">{{submit_text}}</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following piece of code:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        articles = self.get_articles_formsets()
        if not all((x.is_valid() for x in articles.values())):
            return self.render(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

You adress it by `self`, but the class itself does not have a render method.
It does however have a `render_to_response` method, which you are probably meaning to call.

Comment: Ohh, yes. you are right.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Not more error with self.render_to_response.
However, something is not going, my formset is never validated even i put the correct data